# Electromagnetic radiation xrays

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

If x-rays are electromagnetic waves then why are they not deflected by electric and magnetic fields...
As x-rays are electromagnetic they are having perpendicularly oscillating electric and magnetic fields then it should interact with other electromagnetic fields and cause deflections
But that is not the case....

Answer (score 2):

Electromagnetic fields **do not interact** directly with each other*. This is true for the entire electromagnetic spectrum, from gamma rays to radio waves. If you cause two electromagnetic waves to intersect at some point, they will *interfere* at that point (i.e. their fields will add together), but once they pass each other, they are *exactly the same* as if they had never intersected another electromagnetic wave, which is why we say they do not interact.

*Technically, everything in this paragraph doesn't apply to very, *very* high-energy electromagnetic fields (specifically, when the energy of an individual photon is in the tens of GeV - for perspective, this is about a *thousand* times more energetic than the gamma rays coming from nuclear reactors, so you'll never encounter these outside of the LHC or certain energetic quasars). These photons are energetic enough to significantly mix with the heavier $W$ and $Z$ bosons, which means they can interact with each other via this channel in a phenomenon known as *light-by-light scattering*. Let me emphasize that the energy required for this process is so extreme that it basically doesn't happen outside of the most extreme situations in the universe, and even then it's pretty rare, and doesn't last long enough to really call it radiation in most cases, so it's safe to say that electromagnetic radiation in general doesn't interact with other electromagnetic radiation.